# Is there a way to read the data behind this interactive map?

Tags: html, interactive

I'm looking at an [interactive map](https://www.investorseurope.com/markets/overview/) that allows me to set a filter (button "Select Markets") and then places dots on the map which give summary data when I hover the mouse over a dot or detailed information when I click on one. I would like to access the data behind this map.

In Firefox, I pressed <kbd>F12</kbd>, clicked on "Inspector", and drilled down to `body > article > div > div > div > div > div class="map"`. In there, I find a whole lot of data that appear to relate to mouse actions, but I don't find any of the data that are displayed when performing those actions. Is there a way to access the data?

Comment: Look at data.json file.  There are a bunch of javascript files, but data appears to be in that file.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat - Bingo! Please post that as an answer, so I can accept it. (Interesting: I saw a JSON file yesterday and looked at it, and it didn't seem to contain the data. But now, looking again, I see "/assets/js/data.json", and it does appear to contain all the data of the map. It's definitely not the same JSON file I saw yesterday, but it's the only JSON file linked in the HTML of the page, so I don't know what's going on. But I got the data, so thank you.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is in a file *data.json*.  Data format:

```
{
"name": "NASDAQ OMX BX (BEX)",
"country": "US",
"instruments": [
  "Stocks",
  "AtlasTrader",
  "ArcticTrader",
  "Maybank"
]
},
```

There are many levels to that web site, so I'd expect multiple JSON files.  You just have to know where to look.